# MyTest1.exe has triggered a breakpoint on delete command, in C++ / MFC program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I get the message "MyTest1.exe has triggered a breakpoint" when executing a "delete" command in the following code:

```
void Test::delPt(int i)
{
    delete pt[i];
    pt[i] = NULL;
}

void Test::clrPts()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n_pts; i++)
        delPt(i);
    n_pts = 0;
}
```

The array is declared as follows:

```
BasePt *pt[NUM_PTS];
```

... and each array element is created using the "new" command.  There is no code in the BasePt destructor.  I'm not sure what is going on here, I can provide more details if necessary.  I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Is `NUM_PTS == n_pts`?

Comment: Does the message have more information associated with it, like the reason for the breakpoint?  Perhaps an assertion failure due to heap corruption?  I'd examine the code you haven't shown us very carefully for accessing your arrays out of bounds.

Comment: Another possibility would be `Test` not following Rule of Three and you had a copy at some point.

Comment: Check the Visual Studio 'Output' window. It usually has additional information about the error.

Comment: It is some sort of heap problem the program stops on this instruction:         _ASSERTE(_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)); in dbgheap.c

Comment: Your code seems fine, so the problem is probably 1) you are calling delPt() with an invalid i -- please answer wolfPack88's question; 2) Your pt array does not indeed have all the elements pointing to a valid BasePt object.

Comment: NUM_PTS is the maximum, 32.  In my test program n_pts = 2.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by some sort of heap corruption.  By using Visual Leak Detector I was able to eliminate any leakage problems, however the problem remains.  I tried to reduce the program until the problem did not occur and then add back in bits of code, but this did not lead me to find the root of the problem.  My question is how in general can I find the root of heap corruption?  There must be a first point in the program where the heap is corrupted.

(Update) eventually I found the bug, it was some heap corruption in another part of my code.  In fairness I could not have posted all my code as my project is quite large.  I did not know that it was a heap corruption problem when I posted the original message.  Not sure why I got all the negative votes.